# Canon i-sensys LBP7010C

Tags: printing, canon

I downloaded the Linux drivers from Canon's support site and installed them. The installation was apparently easy under the Ubuntu Software-Center (12.04), but the printer doesn't react at all to print jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the application for the Cannon LBP printers in Ubuntu Main Repository.

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-cjet
```